# How can I update a particular variable in an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that contains items, each of which has an ng-click.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-click="clickMe()">Show Item</div>
    <div ng-show="show_item" ng-init="show_item = false>Item 1: {{item.name}}</div>
</div>

$scope.clickMe = function () {
    $scope.show_item = !$scope.show_item
};
```

The problem is that I end up with a list of items that all have the `show_item` variable. For example, if I end up with a list of 10 items, and I click on the second item in the list, then how can I get angular to know that I want to show the 2nd item, and not one of the other items in the list?

Answer (score 0):

All your items are sharing the scope variable `show_item`. you have to create this variable for each item
 Change your `ng-show` and `ng-init` to `ng-show="item.show_item"` and `ng-init="item.show_item = false"`. Also `ng-click="clickMe(item)"`

```
$scope.clickMe = function (item) {
  item.show_item = !item.show_item
};
```